# RecyclerView when to use ItemDecoration vs onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm making a messaging feature in my app that displays a conversation between multiple users. For user-owned messages, I want to align an avatar image to the right, and for other messages, I want the avatar aligned to the left.

In order to achieve this, I have my views inside a framelayout and inside the onBindViewholder method, I programmatically set the gravity of my views and other layoutparam changes. 
I'm wondering about the proper usage of ItemDecorations for this case. Would it be better to have this layout code in my ItemDecorator's getItemOffsets() method instead? Should onBindViewHolder only be responsible for binding my data with my xml views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you set the gravity etc. in your [`onBindViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) method, because these elements are part of the view. And [`ItemDecoration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) is usually used to draw something out of the view or above it - separators, margins, borders etc.

In addition you might create 2 types of view holder with different layouts - one for each side of the conversation (received vs. sent messages) and don't bother setting gravity each time.

Comment: Thanks. regarding viewholders. Say a conversation has 4 different view types. Having a left/right viewholders would force me to have 8 different viewtypes. From what I understand, this causes the recyclerview to create 8 different pools of views to recycle. Would this still be more efficient than having 4 different viewtypes and setting the gravity? What would the tradeoffs be? Thanks!